# How to collect errors is scala and then throw all of them together

Tags: scala, error-handling, jvm

Here is my function:

```
val timeComparator: Function[String, String] = new Function[String, String] {
  def something() {
  //Does some time calculation
  }

  override def apply(element: CharSequence, element1: CharSequence): Any = {
     if (something(parameter1, parameter2)) {
          Left(sys.error("Does not work"))
     } 
  }
}

val callingFunction: Unit = {
  timeComparator(parameter1, parameter2)
}


trait Function[A, B, C] {
  def apply(element : String, element1 :String): Any
}
```

Now this code is run every time new data is available, if it fails then it should throw an error. How do I collect these errors, instead of processing data and throwing error consecutively, I want it to process all of the data together( while not throwing error), and then at the end throw something like "Here is a list of 50 data points that failed", essentially accumulate the errors, instead of throwing them the moment they are created. I am new to Scala and not so familiar with error handling in Scala.

Comment: Unclosed parentheses in `(something(parameter1, parameter2)` . `if (...) Left else None` does not make any sense, especially not if you want to return `Unit` anyway. Take a look at [`Validated`](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/validated.html).

Comment: I am sure you noticed that this a kind of pseudo code, don't pay attention to literal details, this code is just to explain what I wish to achieve.

Comment: @MilapJhumkhawala While we don't expect your code, we can't help you debug code we can't see. In this case, I have no idea what ```something``` returns, or why a function that returns `Left` or `Unit` as an `Any` would be useful. Are there side effects going on somewhere and you just want to accumulate errors? Do you need both the valid results and the errors returned?

Answer (score 3):

You can't collect multiple errors and then "throw all of them". What you can do is collect `Throwable`s wrapped in a `Try.Failure()`.

I'd usually try to demonstrate this concept by plugging it in to your use case, but your "pseudo code" makes no sense and does nothing to clarify what you're trying to accomplish. So instead I'll put together a simple example and hope that you'll be able to transfer it to your situation.

Here's a method that can throw two different types of errors.

```
def calc(in :Int) :Int =
  if (4/in < 1)                 //can throw ArithmeticException
    throw new Error("too big")  //can throw java.lang.Error
  else
    4 * in
```

Let's change it. Instead of throwing the errors, let's return the errors.

```
import util.Try

def calc(in :Int) :Try[Int] = Try{
  if (4/in < 1)                 //can throw ArithmeticException
    throw new Error("too big")  //can throw java.lang.Error
  else
    4 * in
}
```

Now let's feed it some data.

```
val data = 0 to 5
val results = data.map(calc)
//results: Seq[Try[Int]] = Seq(Failure(java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero)
//                           , Success(4), Success(8), Success(12), Success(16)
//                           , Failure(java.lang.Error: too big))
```

From here we can separate the good from the bad and act accordingly.

```
val (good,bad) = results.partition(_.isSuccess)
report_these_numbers(good.map(_.get))  //Seq(4, 8, 12, 16)
log_these_errors(bad)   //Seq(Failure(java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero)
                        //  , Failure(java.lang.Error: too big))
```